# delete jobs by grepping qstat output and sending jobid to qdel?

Tags: bash, grep, pbs

I am using PBS job scheduler on my cluster, and I would like to delete jobs older than a certain date using `qdel`; alternatively it would be sufficient to be able to sort the results of `qstat` by date.

`qstat` gives this output:

```
job-ID  prior   name       user         state submit/start at     queue                          slots ja-task-ID 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 326539 0.50500 run        user         r     01/06/2011 11:13:34 all.q@compute-0-0.local            1        
 326594 0.50500 run        user         r     01/06/2011 11:13:34 all.q@compute-0-0.local            1
```

and I can delete jobs with `qdel`:

```
qdel 326539
```

and the jobs I want to delete can be located using `grep`:

```
qstat > foo; grep 01/06 foo
```

my current work around is to paste the output from above into a spreadsheet, sort by job-ID, and then `qdel {min..max}`,

Can I combine these steps into a single command?

Assistance appreciated.

Comment: @siegeX you are correct, I have fixed the typo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### awk

```
qstat | awk '$6 ~ "01/06" {cmd="qdel " $1; system(cmd); close(cmd)}'
```

#### Bash

```
#!/bin/bash

match="01/06"

while read job; do
  set -- $job
  if [[ $6 =~ $match ]]; then
    qdel "$1"
  fi
done < <(qstat)
```

If you want to do a dry-run, then change `qdel "$1"` to `echo qdel "$1"` to see what it would have done.